# g++ ok but clang no: return rvalue to lvalue

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

I have the following example which is fine by g++, but C/E by clang++.
I wonder who is right among them?

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass() {
    std::cout << "DC" << std::endl;
  }
  MyClass(const MyClass&) {
    std::cout << "CC" << std::endl;
  }
  MyClass(MyClass&&) {
    std::cout << "MC" << std::endl;
  }
  ~MyClass() {
    std::cout << "Destruct C" << std::endl;
  }
};

template<typename T>
decltype(auto) func4(T&& x) {
  return x; // g++ - fine ; clang++ - ERROR
}

int main() {
  MyClass mc;
  func4(std::move(mc));
  return 0;
}
```

error msg:

```
$ clang++-12 --std=c++14 ./ex_001_decltype_auto.cpp -o ./ex_001_decltype_auto
./ex_001_decltype_auto.cpp:42:10: error: rvalue reference to type 'MyClass' cannot bind to lvalue of type 'MyClass'
  return x;
```

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? gcc 11 and later gives the same error as clang. If you want to fix the problem: `return std::forward<T>(x);`

Comment: Pls don't use abbrs everywhr. It makes reading unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: @TedLyngmo gcc 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is legal since C++23, see [P2266R3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2266r3.html). GCC 13+ and Clang 13+ [both implement it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) (both accept your code in C++23 mode), while MSVC doesn't yet.

This paper (among other things) extends the implicit move (that happens when returning a local variable that's either not a reference or an rvalue reference) to apply regardless of the return type, while it used to only work when returning non-references.

Comment: Thanks! Funny to note, that for g++-10 it was a working example all along)

Comment: @unegare It didn't really work, it incorrectly returned an lvalue reference (for rvalue input). GCC 11 and newer will correctly try to return an rvalue reference (and fail before C++23).

Comment: @HollyBlackCat 
as a matter of fact, as for me,
`g++-10 (Ubuntu 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.5.0` compiles it just fine

Comment: @unegare My point is, it compiles, but the return type is wrong (lvalue reference when it should be an rvalue one).

Comment: Oh, now I get it! That's why there was no invocation of move constructor! You have just hit the spot! Enlightenment!